# Adjust table column width to content size

Tags: html, css, css-tables

**Form** (with firebug highlight hover the td):

[image: example]

**Label column CSS**:

```
width: auto;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

**The problem**:

Why my left columns have that invisible "padding-right"? It's not possible to shrink columns to fit their content?

**--EDIT--**

The problem was the table itself. I defined table with "width: 100%". Removed that and the problem is gone.

Comment: Absolutely right! +1 for that :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS table column autowidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757844/css-table-column-autowidth)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem was the table width. I had used `width: 100%` for the table. The table columns are adjusted automatically after removing the width tag.

Comment: Style 'display: block' must be removed if exist.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the table to still be 100% then set one of the columns to have a width:100%; That will extend that column to fill the extra space and allow the other columns to keep their auto width :)

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

maybe problem with margin?

```
width:auto;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px
```

Comment: I added "margin: 0" to my post but it's not the problem.

Comment: <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>?