# Table columns: width, min-width, word wrapping and column "importance"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got three columns in the table of `width: 100%`.

- 2nd and 3rd column should be `width: 100px` no matter what
- 3rd column should be as much as it needs (no wrapped lines), but nothing more.
- 1st column should consume all the remaining space.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o66czLtj/4/

Please note both the 1st and the 4th column don't have the `width` specified, so their widths are counted automatically by the browser. However, I want the 1st column to be the most important, and take all the remaining space, but only after the 4th column was able to render itself without wrapping any lines.

Actual:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

**How to achieve this without hard-coding the width of the 1st or the 4th column?** Perfectly with CSS only.

Rationale: number of buttons in the 4th column is unknown. It may be 1, it may be 4.

Comment: You could do it with `.col1 { width: 80% }`

Comment: you know roughly the width of the "delete" column, why dont you add width to that as wel as .col2 and .col3?

Comment: And what if `.col4` has so many buttons that it's going to take approx. 40% of the table? http://jsfiddle.net/9oxnu8km/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267268/1669475). If you give the 4th column `width: 1px; white-space: nowrap;` then it should occupy the minimum space it can without affecting its content.

```
.col4 {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just add

`Float: right`

To column 2 and 3?

See fiddle below :)

http://jsfiddle.net/r7b3hny7/

I think this is what you're after?

Comment: Yes, it is! I didn't know `float` works this way on tables. Clever! I'll accept this answer if no cleaner solution comes. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! :) To be honest, neither did I until I tried it! Haha!

Comment: Really? :O I'm on Firefox!

Comment: Yep, my Firefox doesn't like it. Chrome does.