# How to get the <td> in HTML tables to fit content, and let a specific <td> fill in the rest

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

This is a hypothetical example:

```css
table, thead, tbody, tr { width: 100%; }
    table { table-layout: fixed }
    table > thead > tr > th { width: auto; }
```

```html
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column A</th>
          <th>Column B</th>
          <th>Column C</th>
          <th class="absorbing-column">Column D</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data A.1 lorem</td>
          <td>Data B.1 ip</td>
          <td>Data C.1 sum l</td>
          <td>Data D.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data A.2 ipsum</td>
          <td>Data B.2 lorem</td>
          <td>Data C.2 some data</td>
          <td>Data D.2 a long line of text that is long</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data A.3</td>
          <td>Data B.3</td>
          <td>Data C.3</td>
          <td>Data D.3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to have every single column's width to fit its content size, and leave the rest of the space for the one column with the "absorbing-column" class, so that it looks like this:

```
| HTML                                                                   | 100%
| body                                                                   | 100%
| table                                                                  | 100%
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Column A | Column B       | Column C | Column D                        |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Column A | Column B lorem | Column C | Column D                        |
| Column A | Column B       | Column C | Column D                        |
| Column A | Column B       | Column C | Column D                        |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

You see, Column B is a bit bigger than the rest due to the extra data in the first row, but Column D always uses up the remaining space.

I played around with max-width, min-width, auto, etc. and could not figure out how to make this work.

In other words, I want all columns to take whatever width they need and not more, and then I want Column D to use up all of the remaining space inside the 100% width table.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

### Define width of .absorbing-column

Set `table-layout` to `auto` and define an extreme width on `.absorbing-column`.

Here I have set the `width` to `100%` because it ensures that this column will take the maximum amount of space allowed, while the columns with no defined width will reduce to fit their content and no further.

This is one of the quirky benefits of how tables behave. The `table-layout: auto` algorithm is mathematically forgiving.

You may even choose to define a `min-width` on all `td` elements to prevent them from becoming too narrow and the table will behave nicely.

```css
table {
    table-layout: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table .absorbing-column {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
      <th>Column C</th>
      <th class="absorbing-column">Column D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data A.1 lorem</td>
      <td>Data B.1 ip</td>
      <td>Data C.1 sum l</td>
      <td>Data D.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data A.2 ipsum</td>
      <td>Data B.2 lorem</td>
      <td>Data C.2 some data</td>
      <td>Data D.2 a long line of text that is long</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data A.3</td>
      <td>Data B.3</td>
      <td>Data C.3</td>
      <td>Data D.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The "absorbing-column" class doesn't apply to "th" however?

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper Good catch. I've updated my example to apply the class only to `th` like the OP's snippet and I've modified the CSS to match. But the effect is the same because, as I point out, the table-layout algorithm is forgiving. The width applied to even one cell in the column, if not overridden by a rule of greater specificity, will result in the width being applied to all cells in the column. If different widths are applied to separate cells by two or more rules of the same specificity, the greatest width is used to layout that column (this seems to be true in Chrome anyway).

Comment: In my experiments, this answer does not prevent the first columns to have content wrapped. The @Vitorino Fernandes answer works better in my opinion.

Comment: That's a good observation. I didn't include the `white-space: nowrap` rule in my answer because it can result in the table overflowing its container, which is undesirable, but I should have directly explained that. I did mention that `min-width` can be used on the `td` elements, which can achieve a similar effect, but it didn't directly address the OPs requirements.

I also like @Vitorino fernandes answer. Though, it too may be improved by resetting `white-space: normal` on `table td:last-child` to help avoid container overflow.

Comment: table-layout: auto worked in my case actually

Answer (score 43):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ywevz8ra/

added border for better view (testing)

more info about [**white-space**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```
table{
    width:100%;
}
table td{
    white-space: nowrap;  /** added **/
}
table td:last-child{
    width:100%;
}
```

```css
    table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    table td {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    table td:last-child {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
      <th>Column C</th>
      <th class="absorbing-column">Column D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data A.1 lorem</td>
      <td>Data B.1 ip</td>
      <td>Data C.1 sum l</td>
      <td>Data D.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data A.2 ipsum</td>
      <td>Data B.2 lorem</td>
      <td>Data C.2 some data</td>
      <td>Data D.2 a long line of text that is long</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data A.3</td>
      <td>Data B.3</td>
      <td>Data C.3</td>
      <td>Data D.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would this work if the "absorbing column" is not at the end (of course, I mean instead of using :last-child, can I use a class and it affects any column the same)?

Comment: yes but you will need to add `.absorbing column` for all the last child [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ywevz8ra/1/) @user2985898

Comment: @user2985898 - Looks like you can use `nth-child` to specify the column: http://jsfiddle.net/5ht73hpc/

Comment: If the text is wider that the cell, it will make the table wider than its container

Comment: @DanV To solve the table wider than its container, simply add 'white-space: initial;' to the 'td:last-child'.

Comment: This solution worked for me as presented.

Answer (score 1):

Setting CSS width to 1% or 100% of an element according to all specs I could find out is related to the parent. Although Blink Rendering Engine (Chrome) and Gecko (Firefox) at the moment of writing seems to handle that 1% or 100% (make a columns shrink or a column to fill available space) well, it is not guaranteed according to all CSS specifications I could find to render it properly.

One option is to replace table with CSS4 flex divs:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

That works in new browsers i.e. IE11+ see table at the bottom of the article.

Answer (score -5):

use overflow:

```
overflow: visible;
```