# How to make the left-most column fit to content in vertical table?

Tags: vmware-clarity

Is there a way to make the left most column fit to it's content in a vertical table?
[image: See this screenshot]
Expectation:
[image]
Actual:
[image]

Comment: Can you show a reproduction of what you mean? Are you just using a normal table? I suggest you review thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915087/how-to-get-the-td-in-html-tables-to-fit-content-and-let-a-specific-td-fill/26915414

Comment: @JeremyWilken No it's not a normal table. It's a vertical table in Clarity UI. What I need is to make the labels column to fit to the longest text in all of the rows and the remaining space will stretch with the values column. Please see edited description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the <td> in HTML tables to fit content, and let a specific <td> fill in the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915087/how-to-get-the-td-in-html-tables-to-fit-content-and-let-a-specific-td-fill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to auto-fit a columns width to its content using css.
On the th element you want to fit to content, add this class:

```
.auto-fit {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

StackBlitz with running code is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-52815432-auto-fit-width-to-content

Comment: Thanks @hippeelee I forked your stackblitz I was able to achieve what I wanted with these css classes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-52815432-auto-fit-width-to-content-vrzzfr

Answer (score 0):

```css
.auto-fit-vertical th {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.auto-fit-vertical td {
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-compact table-vertical auto-fit-vertical">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <td style="font-weight: bold">{{user?.userName}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <td>{{user?.email}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Email Confirmed</th>
                                <td [ngStyle]="{ color: user?.emailConfirmed ? 'green' : 'red' }">
                                    <clr-icon [attr.shape]="user?.emailConfirmed ? 'check' : 'times'"></clr-icon>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Recovery Email</th>
                                <td>{{user?.recoveryEmail}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                                <td>{{user?.mobileNo}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Phone Number</th>
                                <td>{{user?.phoneNumber}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Phone Number Confirmed</th>
                                <td [ngStyle]="{ color: user?.phoneNumberConfirmed ? 'green' : 'red' }">
                                    <clr-icon [attr.shape]="user?.phoneNumberConfirmed ? 'check' : 'times'"></clr-icon>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Is System Administrator</th>
                                <td [ngStyle]="{ color: user?.isSystemAdministrator ? 'green' : 'red' }">
                                    <clr-icon [attr.shape]="user?.isSystemAdministrator ? 'check' : 'times'"></clr-icon>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Is Two-Factor Enabled</th>
                                <td [ngStyle]="{ color: user?.twoFactorEanbled ? 'green' : 'red' }">
                                    <clr-icon [attr.shape]="user?.twoFactorEanbled ? 'check' : 'times'"></clr-icon>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Is Lockout Enabled</th>
                                <td [ngStyle]="{ color: user?.lockout ? 'green' : 'red' }">
                                    <clr-icon [attr.shape]="user?.lockout ? 'check' : 'times'"></clr-icon>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Is Confirmed</th>
                                <td [ngStyle]="{ color: user?.confirmed ? 'green' : 'red' }">
                                    <clr-icon [attr.shape]="user?.confirmed ? 'check' : 'times'"></clr-icon>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Is Active</th>
                                <td [ngStyle]="{ color: user?.active ? 'green' : 'red' }">
                                    <clr-icon [attr.shape]="user?.active ? 'check' : 'times'"></clr-icon>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Date Created</th>
                                <td>{{user?.dateCreated|date:'long'}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```