# How to shrink width of all but one table cell (<td>)?

Tags: css, word-wrap, css-tables, tablecell

I have researched this and the solutions I have found, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26915414/989468) use

```
table {
    table-layout: auto;
}
```

However, I need

```
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
```

because it is the only thing that works for wrapping text in one cell (Contact Message) which has a long message. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263630/989468). The other cells in that table are short words, but the columns are much wider than the actual word.  So, how can I autofit those cells which contain less text but give maximum width to the Contact Message cell (it cannot be the last column) that has the long message.  Note that I am also using the following:

```
.Main {
    width: 95%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

where Main is the containing Div.  See HTML below:

```
<div class="Main">      
<table id="ContactTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Contact Name</th>
                <th>Contact Email</th>
                <th>Contact Phone</th>
                <th>Contact Subject</th>
                <th>Contact Message</th>
                <th>Contact Date</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
```