# How to set column width based on the widest cell

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on an angular 8 project at work. I have a page that displays a table. As per the current code the width of each column was set like below. Widths are only set for `th` and not for `td`

```
.data-table tr th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 10%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 16%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 18%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 18%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 15%;
}
.data-table tr th:nth-child(7) {
  width: 5%;
}
```

First column in table is `Title`. I want width of `title` to be set such that it fits the longest `Title` in every row. Is there a way to do this without Javascript??

Comment: You can use `min-width` here and for left columns define `width: auto`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fit cell width to content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267154/fit-cell-width-to-content)

Comment: @NishargShah setting `min-width` and `width: auto` isn't working. Also from what I knew `min-width` didn't work on tables.

Comment: What?? Who said `width` property does not work on the table?

Comment: Width works, I'm setting width in my code. However I tried setting min-width but it doesn't work

Comment: please see `inspect element`, some CSS property overcome your `min-width`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that in less code.

```
.data-table tr th:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 20%;
}

.data-table tr th:nth-child(2), .data-table tr th:nth-child(3), .data-table tr th:nth-child(4), .data-table tr th:nth-child(5), .data-table tr th:nth-child(6) {
  max-width: 15%;
}

.data-table tr th:nth-child(7) {
  width: 5%;
}
```

**SHORT VERSION**

```
.data-table tr th:first-child {
  min-width: 20%;
}

.data-table tr th:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  max-width: 15%;
}

.data-table tr th:last-child {
  width: 5%;
}
```