# How can I make the width of a <td> to auto?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way I can specify the margin of a `<td>` so that the width of automatically adjusts to make the table as wide as its parent (width: 100%;)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS table column autowidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757844/css-table-column-autowidth)

Comment: The title and body of your question do not match. The title asks about setting the width of a table cell to auto (whatever that means), whereas the body asks something about setting the margin of a table cell (which doesn't exist) so the width of the table is as wide as its parent.  The current proposed duplicate answers the title question.

Answer (score 1):

*By creating a table in HTML for example like:*

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Header</td>
            <td class="smallCell">Small Fit</td>
            <td>Header</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

*and for adjusting the width with CSS do add like:*

```
table
{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
//enter according to the size requirement
```