# limiting column width in html

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have built the following table:

```
    <table id="viewConfigurationTable" style="width:700px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100px">Id</td>
        <td style="width:100px">Name</td>
        <td style="width:200px">Status</td>
        <td style="width:300px">Ctids</td>
        <td style="width:300px">CreationDate</td>
    </tr>

    <% foreach (var config in Model.AliveConfigurations)
       {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=config.Id%></td>
        <td><%=config.Name%></td>
        <td><%=config.Status%></td>
        <td><%=config.Ctids%></td>
        <td><%=config.CreationDate%></td>

    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
```

and yet the `Ctids` column get really wide sometimes.

How can I fix this?

Comment: FYI: Your table width is set to 700px but the total width of all your columns is 1000px.

Comment: I think you need to give width for all tds of the other row(s) as well.(The one inside foreach loop)..

Comment: did u tried max-width: and word-wrap:break-word;

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537285/adjust-table-column-width-to-content-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, tables width are "not usable", you could try to make them `div`'s.

But if you really need tables to be fixed, change the widths of `TD`'s to match table width, add `table-layout:fixed` to table as style and set `TD`'s to break words: `word-wrap:break-word`.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MJFHG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <style type="text/css">
    table {
      width: 25%;//use this value for the table size compared to the screen size.
    }
    table td {
      width:auto;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  </style>

    <table id="viewConfigurationTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Ctids</td>
            <td>CreationDate</td>
        </tr>

        <% foreach (var config in Model.AliveConfigurations)
           {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=config.Id%></td>
            <td><%=config.Name%></td>
            <td><%=config.Status%></td>
            <td><%=config.Ctids%></td>
            <td><%=config.CreationDate%></td>

        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
```

Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MJFHG/2/)